# Laravel foreign key saves issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table named `companies` and other table named `ads`, I try to get company id in ads column named `company_id`.

This is my ads migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('ads', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ads');
    }
}
```

this will create me ads table with no problem but when i try to save ads it returns me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jobid`.`ads`, CONSTRAINT `ads_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `ads` (`title`, `slug`, `description`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (first ad test, first-ad-test, <p>rwv R4QF Q4R</p>, 1494998776.png, 2017-05-17 12:26:17, 2017-05-17 12:26:17))
```

How can I fix that?

UPDATE

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('manager_name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->text('about')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Store function

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, array(
      'title' => 'required|max:255',
      'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:ads,slug',
      'image' => 'sometimes|image',
      'description' => 'required'
    ));

    $ad = new Ad;

    $ad->title = $request->input('title');
    $ad->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $ad->description = $request->input('description');


    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
      $avatar = $request->file('image');
      $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $location = public_path('ads/');
      $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);


      $ad->image = $filename;
    }

    $ad->save();


      Session::flash('success', 'Your ad published successfully!');

      return redirect()->route('company.adslist', $ad->id);
  }
```

Comment: post your company schema

Comment: @SapneshNaik already

Comment: You have to make sure to send `company_id` to the table. you are passing everything except `company_id`.

_**insert into `ads` (`title`, `slug`, `description`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (first ad test, first-ad-test, <p>rwv R4QF Q4R</p>, 1494998776.png, 2017-05-17 12:26:17, 2017-05-17 12:26:17))**_

Comment: @Priya how?! should is say `'company_id' => '?????',`  or in down `$ad->company_id= $request->??????;` that's what i don't know.

Comment: `$ad->company_id = [company_id]` // if your url is `example.com/company/[id]/ads` then $request->id based on your router which should hold `->post('/company/{id}/ads', [controller])`;
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#accessing-the-request The first example says how to access id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in your company form
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value ="{{ company_id }}">
```

then in store method

```
  $ad->company_id=Input::get('company_id');
```

you can make the id dynamic according to user input, i am just hardcoding for the moment

Comment: so you say if i change title and company_id in migration will fix?

Comment: no, bro understand the problem, the company id is not getting passed in the query when you are trying to save, can post the code from where the error is coming

Comment: where should i pass it? in my adcontroller?

Comment: in adcontroller store function

Comment: then add it there, pass the company_id too

Comment: i already updated my store function would you please check it?

Comment: @expator thanks man, how i make it dynamic cause there will be lot's of companies and lots of ads.

Comment: tell me the logic you want to implement, because without knowing what you want to do i cant say

Comment: the logic is like this: `companies` is user table who can publish ads, their ads will be save in `ads` table as an `ad` now i need to get each company(user) id for each ad to know which ad was published by which company.

Comment: how are you going to do that? by form? means the user will select the company right? then you will display the ads?

Comment: no, ads will be shown in paginated page and categories then users(visitors) just click the link and view the ad in there has info of the company who published the ad.   so for eg. in each page could be ads of tens of different companies.

Comment: that is a different part, for that you have to get company details using the ads id, but for store how are you doing it? means how a company will add a new ad?

Comment: i created a form in companies dashboard where they can publish ads.  currently has this fields: title, slug,description and image. they fulfill data in that form and click publish then they see this error which made me to ask this question here :)

Comment: so put an hidden field for the company id there, so that you can know which company is publishing the add, i will edit the answer, do it like that, it will solve your storing problem

Comment: dont forget to upvote and verify the ans if you like it @robertnicjoo

Comment: it gets me error again i follow instructions and end up with these codes `<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value ="{{ 'company_id' }}">` and `$ad->company_id = $request->Input('company_id');` but except saving data will refresh the page.

Comment: now with your edited code i'm getting this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jobid`.`ads`, CONSTRAINT `ads_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `ads` (`company_id`, `title`, `slug`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ([1], ewfwf, wgweg, <p>wgwg</p>, 2017-05-17 13:50:40, 2017-05-17 13:50:40))`

Comment: yes bro how are you passing the company id to the form?? so that it will display {{ company id }}

Comment: ok, i did change the code to this `<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value ="@foreach ($companies as $company){{ $company->id }}@endforeach">` and in source page codes value is correct now but when i hit save will get this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jobid`.`ads`, CONSTRAINT `ads_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `ads` (`company_id`, `title`, `slug`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ([1], ....)`

Comment: ok man, i did it with changing store code to this `$ad->company_id = $request->Input('company_id');` and now it's working just fine.  I appreciate what you've done. GBU

Comment: you are passing multiple companies bro, see bro the thing is that, when a company creates an ad, that companies id needs to be in the hidden input and not all. you need to figure out that, k how you are going to pass the id for that company to the form, and rest will work perfectly

Comment: in create method i have this `public function create()
  {
      $companies = Company::find(Auth::user());
      return view('company.create', compact('companies'));
  }` to get the exact company info and i pass company id to the form by foreach, you think it's going to be messy in future?   **You made me confuse with last comment :) **